# Fast unique integer generation

Tags: c#, optimization, statistics

#### Background

I'm writing a Cribbage statistics calculator.  At first I made it calculate the point values of every possible 5-card hand, and checked it against [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage_statistics#Odds) until my numbers were the same as theirs.

Now I'm calculating every possible pair of two hands (your hand and the crib), some 2.3 trillion combinations, so optimization is key.

#### Code

Cards have all been assigned numbers between 0 and 51.  The `Hand` constructor takes an `int[]` of length five, and assumes the last card is the starter card.  Now that all the point-calculating code is taken care of, I want to optimize the hand card-number generating process.

Right now I have:

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int[], int[]>> GetTwoHands()
{
    bool[] avail = new bool[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        avail[i] = true;
    }

    // hand 1 cards
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        avail[i] = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 52; j++)
        {
            avail[j] = false;
            for (int k = j + 1; k < 52; k++)
            {
                avail[k] = false;
                for (int l = k + 1; l < 52; l++)
                {
                    avail[l] = false;

                    // hand 2 (crib) cards
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 52; i2++)
                    {
                        if (!avail[i2])
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        avail[i2] = false;
                        for (int j2 = i2 + 1; j2 < 52; j2++)
                        {
                            if (!avail[j2])
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            avail[j2] = false;
                            for (int k2 = j2 + 1; k2 < 52; k2++)
                            {
                                if (!avail[k2])
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                avail[k2] = false;

                                for (int l2 = k2 + 1; l2 < 52; l2++)
                                {
                                    if (!avail[l2])
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    avail[l2] = false;

                                    // shared starter card
                                    for (int m = 0; m < 52; m++)
                                    {
                                        if (!avail[m])
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }

                                        yield return Tuple.Create(new int[] { i, j, k, l, m }, new int[] { i2, j2, k2, l2, m });
                                    }

                                    avail[l2] = true;
                                }

                                avail[k2] = true;
                            }

                            avail[j2] = true;
                        }

                        avail[i2] = true;
                    }

                    avail[l] = true;
                }

                avail[k] = true;
            }

            avail[j] = true;
        }

        avail[i] = true;
    }
}
```

where `i` through `l` are the first hand's card's numbers, `i2` through `l2` are the second's, and `m` is the card number of the starter card.  Obviously there cannot be duplicates of cards in the hands, so for the second hand, I make sure each card number is not already in hand 1.

I'm using C#'s `IEnumerable<T>.AsParallel().ForAll(action)` to make use of all my processor cores, so `Hand(int[])` happens within the action, rather than `GetTwoHands()` which is synchronous.

#### Questions

- Is there a way to clean up all those loops without sacrificing performance?  I suspect, though haven't tested, that recursion would slow it down because of all of the function calls.
- Is there a faster algorithm for generating these numbers?

Comment: I don't think there is any hope of accomplishing this without applying a completely different, significantly faster algorithm

Comment: I'm fine with that.  What better algorithm could I use?  This was just the best I could come up with, though I am about to edit it slightly.

Comment: A better algorithm is to use Permutations and Combination, see https://github.com/eoincampbell/combinatorics

Comment: Is there any chance you could avoid doing this altogether? Perhaps using some clever math, or a datastructure that can represent this sort of thing implicitly like a ZDD.

Comment: @HABO - no they don't.

Comment: I think that maybe mimicking the actual game is more efficient than that `avail[]` stuff. Lazily generate all permutations of 52 cards and at each permutation, deal 2 hands.

Comment: @Henk I believe that's what I'm doing now.  Using `avail[]` and starting each successive card number after the previous one in the hand is the fastest way I could think of generating each combination (rather than permutation which would be a lot of extra work for no real gain since the order of the cards in each hand don't matter aside from card `m`).  It might be faster to use @Richard's combinatorics package.  I will look into it.

Comment: Java's JIT optimizer can give you hint about maximum performance. Try in java for benchmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming in on this late, but as I've played Cribbage since I was 7 (I'm 52), I might be able to help a bit.

It looks like there's a hint of recursion in other posts. When you're talking about the big numbers, you might as well be iterative and strategic.

I know it's verboten to post URIs, but... it'll save a lot of time.

If you go here:  http://www.cribbagematch.com/, you'll find Tim Schempp's reboot of Royal Crib from a Cribbage package created in 2000, and currently in beta.  There's an email address for reaching him.  I was talking with him the other day and he says he retests his code with ca. 1k games when he makes changes.

The short story made long is that he's put together a couple of docs [in 2000] which provide a lot of insights for the statistics you're looking at generating, plus the underlying algorithm(s) he used in 2000. Just be prepared to see a lot of sigmas. Two PDF documents are roughly just over 40 pages each. Ask him for a copy, as he's been sharing them for many years.  Some of his work ran for days (remember, this was 14 years ago).

If the numbers you want to play with don't fit the information provided, there's enough there to show you how to do some of your own, special calculations. e.g. a single player's 4-card hand, after the throw, can be broken down like this:

- 4 different cards................715
- 1 pair, 2 different..............858
- 2 pair................................78
- 3 of a kind, 1 diff..............156
- 4 of a kind...................... 13
- Total.................................1'820 total combinations

So why brute force and filter duplicates?

e.g. There are 18'395 six card combinations (for one player), 3'274'375 combinations of 4 cards during The Play of player vs. player. Tim points out the number of combinations for The Play (4x4) is within 1% of squaring 1'820.

I think you'll find there's substantially fewer than 2.3T unique sequences if you are more strategic in your methodology:  Are you looking at dealing with a flush? If not, then you don't need to worry about 52 cards, just 13, with 4 occurrences.  Change 52 to 13 and see how manageable those numbers turn out to be.  If you're generating a calculator, you can still want to consider flushes, the math for that is much simpler to calculate on the side vs. dragging it into the middle of calculations you're making.

If nothing else: Check out Martin Broadhurst's web site (it's eponymous) and look at "Combinatorial Algorithms" (it's in C and quite sweet) which will significantly cut down on your numbers - making it possible to manage all of the various combinations/permutations/etc. You're going to be using a couple of different ones to get the data you want. It's also going to make life easier to ensure you're using the correct algorithm.  Most of them allow you to specify mapping into characters so you can substitute a "T" for 10 to make alignment easier as all which will be displayed will be single characters.

Even if you use Martin's library, you can crank out a complete set of data without streamlining the process.

I'm not wanting to chide you for homework - I'm truly curious why you're generating so much raw Cribbage data (it's not common as a recreational exercise)

I've run into a lot of papers not all that long ago (in the 500+ course level, or presentations of Cribbage at a conferences) where they have only generated what's kept in the hand strategically vs. random throws, with an ANN.  They're looking at a small segment of the game (and sometimes, the code isn't right!). For courses at that level, I'm surprised they're able to sneak much past their sponsors. (If only they knew.) Even applying an ANN to The Play would be far more interesting, complex, and quite a bit of fun.

One final thought - here's something most people don't think about - something other than keeping points in your hand:

"You're the dealer, are dealt cards (at random) <1>,<2>,<3>,<4>,<5>,<6>.  You need 5 points to peg out, the pone needs 7.  As the pone will play the first card and will count their hand first, what's your best throw/keep strategy for those six cards?"  (then provide the analysis and see if you can come up with a rule or two on your own).

How about: "If you are the dealer and have 19 in scoring your hand, what are the odds you'll also have 19 in your crib?"  These are the types of insights which make the game interesting.

Comment: Believe it or not, it is merely recreational.  Last year I wrote something to determine the odds of winning a Risk battle starting with x troops vs y troops.  I'm odd that way, I guess.